# Потокобезопасная работа с MultiValueMap

Tags: многопоточность, java

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема - в качестве контейнера использую MultiValueMap из commons-coolection. Ключ - String, Value - ArrayList.К моему Мапу одновременно обращаются несколько потоков, которые читают value(ArrayList), забирают из него какой-то элимент, после чего этот элемент из этого ArrayList удаляется. Проблема в том что я не знаю как правильно это засинхронизировать. Если я буду синхронизировать операции по удалению элемента из ArrayList подобным образом:

```
synchronize(myMap) {
Collection c = myMap.getCollection(key);// Возвращается value - ArrayList
c.get(randomIndex);
c.remove(randomIndex); // Удаление элемента из листа
}
```

будет ли это означать что операции чтения-удаления для моего ArrayList потокобезопасны ? Ведь сам лист не синхронизирован, и как видно из примера, для синхронизации я использую объект блокировки Мапа а не Листа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сделать всё потокобезопасным, то и все операции с листами, полученными из мапы должны быть внутри секции synchronized по этой же мапе (в простом случае). И более того, надо чтобы получение листа из мапы было в **той же** секции, что и операции над ним.

Comment: Ну так у меня так и сделано. Я хотел узнать не нужно ли после получения листа из мапы операции по этому листу синхронизировать по нему же ?

Comment: Нет не нужно. Судя по всему, вы не понимаете сути synchronized, а думаете, будто это какая-то магия, позволяющая синхронизовать объекты. Советую поинтересоваться тем, как работает монитор Хоара и как используется. Ключевое слово synchronized не делает почти ничего с самой мапой. По идее, можно делать synchronized по какому-нибудь другому объекту и получить такой же результат.